# UITableViewCell behaving strange - text changing to white

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a view one top of `UITableView`. If I drag top view out, UITableViewCell text colour is changing to white, even if I am chasing to gray.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.productNameLabel.text = "chi"
    cell.productNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

    return cell
}
```

[image]

If I don't put top view to UITableView then it is showing `grayColor`. I tried to log cell in console when text becomes white.

```
UITableViewCell; 
frame = (0 0; 375 60); 
clipsToBounds = YES; 
hidden = YES; 
autoresize = W; 
layer = <CALayer: 0x604000427da0>>
```

It shows hidden is Yes. I have not set anywhere hidden. Is it because of dequeue issue?

Comment: i think it is using tintColor of topView  in your cell don't know what exactly is happening.

Comment: Do you also have a custom class for your Table View Cell or is it done through prototype cell in the storyboard?

Comment: @Alan - Yes prototype custom cells

Comment: @Cintu try to set the font color in the storyboard

Comment: Its already set to dark gray in storyboard

Comment: Try setting text to some other string, so that you can confirm if this label is appearing from somewhere else? `cell.productNameLabel.text = "some_other_string" `

Answer (score 0):

try with different string and different color,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.productNameLabel.text = "testing label"
    cell.productNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor

    return cell
}
```